# 'Should' vs 'If'

Tags: conditional-constructions

I've noticed that sometimes people use **'should'** instead of '**if**'. But if you replace the word '**should**' by an 'if', it still makes sense.

For example:

> 'Your mission, **should** you choose to accept it'

or

> 'Your mission, **if** you choose to accept it'

Another example:

> 'You must evacuate **if** there is a fire'

or

> 'You must evacuate **should** there be a fire'

Are they always interchangable?

Comment: See [A special use of “should”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/a-special-use-of-should)

Answer (score 3):

You can tell by your second example pair there is something different.

> You must evacuate if there is a fire.
>   You must evacuate should there be a fire.

The word **should** forced you into subjunctive mood, *should there be*.  It would not be wrong to say *if there be*, but many folks are not used to hearing the subjunctive in that context. (They might even consider you wrong or even "backward".) The point is, modern English did not force the subjunctive with **if** but it did with **should**. I am not sure why this is the case, but it could be there is a greater air of uncertainty with **should** -- sort of your anticipation of the possibility along with the possibility itself.

Also consider how moving the word **should** alters a sentence.

1. Go to the store and buy some milk.
2. You should go to the store and buy some milk.
3. Should you go to the store, buy some milk.
4. If you go to the store, buy some milk.

The transition is from a command, to a suggestion, to a conditional suggestion, to a conditional command. With #3 it as almost as if the **Should** supplied its own ", okay?" at the end. The **If** in #4 does not do that; it is just a dry, logical if..then construct.

Comment: I have never heard of **if there be**. Can you give examples from grammar books?

Comment: @SovereignSun It is a little late, but one example is a 2015 movie -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_There_Be_Thorns_(film) .  In my experience, many black folks who speak American English preserve the subjunctive.while most white folks have thrown it away.  Personally I think the subjunctive sounds better.  //  "Were there to be" is perfectly fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

If is more like being just a conditional as in `if` this occurs, while should is more like being forced in the condition.
Like `Should` condition be forced.
That's what I perceive.